# Square bullet bug in DNN / FCKEditor

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net

i am facing a bug which comes in DNN / FCKEditor after creating a default  list. Actually i put my own bullet in custom

.. but the default square bullet also comes with this...

Please tell me how to remove this bug. i try all CSS logics here.

Comment: Tag this with CSS, Javascript, and other stuff to get more eyes on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make css and override `list-style-type` to disc

```
ul li { list-style-type:disc;}
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware thought that this comes form the default.css, so you probably need to override more elements, all the headers for example